# ERROR: Error installing vagrant: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to install vagrant on MacOS (Lion). But it keeps failing.

**What happens...**

sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install vagrant

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing vagrant:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection. Results logged
>   to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out

I have XCode installed (installed it this morning from the AppStore).

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that XCode 4.3 doesn't in command line tools by default (not sure if this is the first version that doesn't do this). Installing them got it working.

Command Line Tools can be installed by going to Preferences > Downloads > Components.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your build was failing, but starting with Vagrant 1.0 (not released yet, but RCs are out), the preferred installation method will be packages, so you can just download a pkg for Mac and install, even without XCode installed: http://downloads.vagrantup.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was to be my alternative if XCode route failed. I wanted XCode so that I can play with iOS too.